# Accessing ids of external css file in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I've a `line of code` like this:

```
 htmlcontent =  htmlcontent+'<div class="checkbox" id="chkpos[j]">'+optionAlpha+'<label class="lclass"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="answer" value='+optionid+'>'+option+'</label>'+htmloptionImage+'</div>';
```

And `ids` in external css are like this:

```
            #chkpos1{
                /*position: relative;*/
                margin-top: 8%;   
            }
            #chkpos2{
                /*position: relative;*/
                margin-top: 26%;   
            }
            #chkpos3{
                /*position: relative;*/
                margin-top: 17%;   
            }
```

How can I make that javascript code (`'<div class="checkbox" id="chkpos[j]">'`) access those ids?
Any ideas?

Comment: I'd avoid using `[` and `]` characters in the id attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by using JS to "access those ids"? JS is mostly used to access DOM elements, not to access CSS rules. Please state your question in a clearer way.

Comment: htmlcontent =  htmlcontent+'<div class="checkbox" id="chkpos'+j+'">';

Comment: @Bhuvana: Please check quotes, they're not in order

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I checked in the console. It works.

Comment: @Bhuvana: Okay, let me try your code

Comment: @Bhuvana: I tried your code. It loaded required page successfully in android, however css rules didn't work.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Please make sure 'j' takes value of 1 to 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81004/discussion-between-ajay-kulkarni-and-bhuvana).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Ids in your CSS (though I recommend using classes instead like Cerbrus said) set your Id like this:

```
htmlcontent =  htmlcontent+'<div class="checkbox" id="chkpos' + j + '">'+optionAlpha+'<label class="lclass"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="answer" value='+optionid+'>'+option+'</label>'+htmloptionImage+'</div>';
```

You can't use `[ ]` brackets in css as Ids as CSS uses these for attributes (such as `input[type=text]`).

Like I said though, I'd recommend using classes, so in your JS:

```
htmlcontent =  htmlcontent+'<div class="checkbox chkpos chkpos' + j + '">'+ //etc...
```

CSS:

```
.chkpos {
    /*position: relative;*/
}
.chkpos1 {
    margin-top: 8%;   
}
.chkpos2 {
    margin-top: 26%;   
}
.chkpos3 {
    margin-top: 17%;   
}
```

Comment: It should be `htmlcontent =  htmlcontent+'<div class="checkbox chkpos' + j + '">'+ //etc...`, right?

Comment: I added the extra chkpos class so that you can give common css rules to all of these checkboxes such as in `.chkpos { /*position: relative;*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

`[]` are invalid characters for element id's (or classes), as they're used in CSS for attributes.

Use classes instead:

```
htmlcontent = htmlcontent +
    '<div class="checkbox" class="chkpos pos' + j + '">' + 
        optionAlpha +
            '<label class="lclass"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="answer" value='+optionid+'>' +
                option +
            '</label>' +
        htmloptionImage +
    '</div>';
```

CSS:

```
.chkpos {
    /*position: relative;*/
}
.chkpos.pos1 {
    margin-top: 8%;   
}
.chkpos.pos2 {
    margin-top: 26%;   
}
.chkpos.pos3 {
    margin-top: 17%;   
}
```

Comment: class names like `.1`, `.2` `.3` are also invalid. A name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z)

Answer (score 0):

avoid [] brackets and i think  **j** use for loop

```
  htmlcontent =  htmlcontent + "<div class="checkbox" class='chkpos " + j + "'>'+optionAlpha+'<label class="lclass"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="answer" value='+optionid+'>'+option+'</label>'+htmloptionImage+'</div>";
```

css

```
.chkpos {
    /*position: relative;*/
}
.chkpos.1 {
    margin-top: 8%;   
}
.chkpos.2 {
    margin-top: 26%;   
}
.chkpos.3 {
    margin-top: 17%;   
}
```

Comment: Does ` id='chkpos " + j + '` access `.chkpos.1`?

Comment: yes it access because i use "chkpos " space given between  text and j

Comment: sorry for i am not change id attribute to class